# Imagick Installation Errors - Class Undefined

Tags: php, imagick

Okay, Here's a breakdown of what's up:

1. `<? $foo = new Imagick(); ?>` works without error when ran from the command-line (e.g., sudo php myscript.php
2. However, when run via the web browswer I get `Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /var/www/lhackwith_www/test_html/magic.php on line 1`.
3. magickwand is not installed
4. extension=imagick.so is in imagick.ini which is successfully being read according to phpInfo();
5. However, imagick is NOT showing up in PHP info.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you're absolutely sure you've edited the right php.ini...
Did you check the webserver's error.log for hints? You might want to increase the LogLevel for that test. If it's an apache see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#errorlog

or maybe [ldd - print shared library dependencies](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ldd+1) can shed some light on the issue:

```
<?php
$p = get_cfg_var('extension_dir');
$modpath = $p.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'imagick.so';
echo $modpath, is_readable($modpath) ? ' readable':' not readable', "<br />\n";
echo '<pre>';
passthru('ldd '.$modpath.' 2>&1'); // in case of spaces et al in the path-argument use escapeshellcmd()
echo '</pre>';
```

please run this script both on the command line and through the webserver. Does it complain about a missing dependency?



edit2: So the script running "within" the webserver isn't even able to see the extension .so... Let's test at which point of the path the trouble starts

```
<?php
function foo($path) {
  if ( $path==($dir=dirname($path)) ) {
    return;
  }
  foo($dir);
```

echo
    is_dir($path) ? ' d':' -',
    is_readable($path) ? 'r':'-',
    is_writable($path) ? 'w':'-',
    is_executable($path) ? 'x ':'- ',
    $path, "<br />\n";
}

$modpath = get_cfg_var('extension_dir').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'imagick.so';
foo($modpath);

Comment: Good advice. However, I checked the log levels and everything else and it just parroted back to me the same "not found" error.

Comment: Is php installed as cgi or as module?

Comment: The apache server is (most probably) using another user account, maybe with a different environment (path, libpath, ...). Let's see if ldd can resolve all dependencies when running on the webserver's "user" account.

Comment: ldd /usr/lib/php/modules/imagick.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00b6b000)
        libWand.so.10 => /usr/lib/libWand.so.10 (0x00497000)
        libMagick.so.10 => /usr/lib/libMagick.so.10 (0x001d8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00658000)
        ....

That's a sample of the output I got from ldd. It appears that I'm not missing any dependencies (everything was installed via YUM on CentOS (imagick 2.2.1)

Comment: /usr/lib/php/modules/imagick.so not readable

ldd: /usr/lib/php/modules/imagick.so: No such file or directory

That's what I get when I run your script

Comment: I also want to note that all other modules in that folder are readable minus imagick.so and that the permissions on imagick.so are wide open (777)

Comment: The first output you got from the command line version and the "not readable/no such file" output is from the webserver test?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with imagick after upgrading ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10.

After much fiddling I eventually discovered that there is a different package needed (for php5?) and fixed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using?  I've had several problems on Mac OSX that basically makes installing some extensions OVERLY painful. However, the Imagick install should be really simple, for most operating systems.

On your command line, type php -i | grep ini, and make sure the php.ini that is listed as being loaded is the same as the php.ini that phpinfo() says is being loaded.  If these are different, that's where you have to start.  Make sure extension=imagick.so is in both ini files, also - verify that they are loading extensions from the same directory (99% chance they will be, but who knows - you could be an exception).

After you've verified that (possibly) both php.ini files are loading imagick.so and it's still not working, try to tail -f /path/to/apache/error_log (assuming you're using apache, of course..) and restart apache.  You're looking here for php warnings about loading libraries and/or extensions. Hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps,

Jim

Comment: Thanks for your help, CentOS is the OS I'm using. The web server is apache.

Comment: Is anything on your system 64bit?

Comment: No, I believe we're running 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:

Storing the orientation of the image in the DB and then using alternatiff to dynamically rotate the image to the orientation that was stored. No image manipulation needed.

Thanks for your help though.